# PHP cURL HTTP-Authentication to let user into password protected directory?

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication, curl, directory

I am building a prototype of a web app for a client, using axure - which is all front-end code (html/css/js files) - no php at all, so i can't use php authentication (sessions, etc) within the prototype itself.

So to protect it, the prototype is in a password-protected directory on my server (using htaccess / basic HTTP Authentication), so my client must login to review it.

But instead of requiring him to login through the ugly browser-based login-box, I'd LOVE to somehow use PHP to login for him, since he'll already be logged into my client-portal (Wordpress) site.

I setup a PHP page outside the prototype directory, and used cURL to hit the prototype's start-page (/project04/start.html) -- and successfully authenticate. But I can't then use cURL to load and display the content from start.html onto that php page, because all the paths (for assets and links) in the prototype become wrong (and there's a ton of JS that might be problematic too).

I tried using header(Location: project04/start.html) in the php, after the cURL login, but that didn't work - the redirect just triggered the ugly http-auth login box again.

Is there any way to use PHP to login, and then let the user into the protected directory, to browse around the prototype?

Alternatively, the prototype works great embedded into an iframe (on a php page of my Wordpress site). But then the prototype directory itself is not actually protected from direct viewing - it's just hidden. I tried moving it outside my document-root, as a way to protect it without htaccess-auth, but then the paths are all bad again.

Any help super appreciated.
Thanks!